# SSL error while doing a request for Microsoft graph api

Tags: python, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api, airflow

I trying to get integrate Microsoft Graph API into the airflow application docker-compose. And I have a self-signed SSL certificate for my domain.

following is the sample of DAG (pythonOperator): [I'm using the `msal` pypi package]

```
app_meta = MicrosoftGraphAPI.get()
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
   app_meta['client_id'],
   authority=app_meta['authority'],
   client_credential=app_meta['client_credential'],
   token_cache=None,
)
```

Error:

```
    WARNING - Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])"))': /d8c857c0-b2da-48fd-9b28-db5792c0d481/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
[2021-06-23 10:19:02,870] {taskinstance.py:1396} ERROR - HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /d8c857c0-b2da-48fd-9b28-db5792c0d481/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 488, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1934, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1671, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 362, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 386, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 494, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError("bad handshake: %r" % e)
```

UPDATE: I don't want to ignore certificate validation. How to fix it

Comment: Can you provide more information about your integration, sample DAG and how are you using the Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: @bruno-uy, update the post

Comment: the server certificate cannot be verified. Do you have the intermediate / root CA certificates available in the certificate chain?

Comment: no idea what it means, I just used `msal` pypi in dag to call graph api

Answer (score 1):

Earlier intermediate CA certificates were optional, but now it is mandatory that you must have all the root and intermediate certificates available in certificate chain. I also faced this issue while connecting to nuget site for downloading packages, so i installed "BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot" , "Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 01" and "DigiCertGlobalRootG2". It worked for me.